# Error with GCC and MinGW

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc

I'm just trying to install MinGW to try to do some C and C++ programming I've never worked with either much before.  I'm using windows 10.  I installed MinGW and created an environmental variable and I have a folder called TestFolder on my desktop with a file called test.c

When I gcc that file I get this error message:

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin                      d -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've tried googling the answer on how to fix it, but the answers seem to be beyond the scope of my knowledge at the moment.  They are mostly talking about some error with the linker (which I think I get what it does, but no idea how to work with it).  Could someone please help teach me how to fix this or at least point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Use a painless installation like TDM - http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

Comment: @NeilButterworth should I uninstall MinGW or does it matter?

Comment: You should uninstall it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Wow thank you!  I've spent all day working on that stupid error and TDM worked perfectly!

Comment: You are very welcome - I don't know why so many people take the hard way to install GCC on Windows. And if you want a low-overhead IDE which works well with TDM GCC, take a look at Code::Blocks.